# How to change fieldset toggle icon?

Tags: extjs, icons, toggle, fieldset

I want to change the default triangle toggle icon to '+' / '-'

```
.legendFieldSet {
    border-width: 0px; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.legendFieldSet .x-tool-toggle{
    background-position: 0 -255px !important; /*the minus sign*/
}

.legendFieldSet .x-panel-collapsed .x-tool-toggle{
    background-position: 0 -240px !important; /*the plus sign*/
}
```

(Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5eWFX/128/).)

What's wrong with what I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do it is this:

```
.legendFieldSet .x-tool-toggle {
    background-position: 0 -255px !important; /*the minus sign*/
}

.legendFieldSet.x-fieldset-collapsed .x-tool-toggle {
    background-position: 0 -240px !important; /*the plus sign*/
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to theme ExtJS is to modify and build their SASS. This way your CSS stays clean and manageable. More info on compiling SASS here, http://www.sencha.com/learn/theming/